# Annimation Issue for IE7 and not IE8

Tags: css

I have an implementation of Animation.

This functions correct in IE8 and Firefox, however this doesnt work in IE7.

http://www.davincispainting.com/generalcontact.aspx

For some reason the Annimation scrolls over top of the Purple Div for IE7, when it should start behind it, as demonstrated in IE8.  Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the z-index style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the div where the animation exists to -1 like this:

```
z-index:-1;
```

**UPDATE**

Box 1 will be the box with the animation:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box1
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
background-color:red;
top:0;
left:100;
}
#box2
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
z-index:1;
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box1">
</div>
<div id="box2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @loyalpenguin do you have IE7 installed?

Comment: @Paul I'm using SuperPreview part of ExpressionWeb. Check my updated answer for an example how to force certain divs to appear in front or in back of each other.

Comment: @loyalpenguin your previous explanation made total sense, thank you for that.  Now Im just looking for a way to check it w/ IE7

Comment: @Paul I recommend you get SuperPreview from Microsoft. It's a part of Expression Web and it lets you check your websites with every version of IE as well as firefox, safari, etc.

Comment: @loyalpenguin you were correct that part of the problem is that I did not include z-index.  Also what was required was that the Div w/ z-index:1 needed to have a background-color.

Comment: @Paul Yeah wouldn't make much sense if it didn't have a background color. Good to hear it worked out.